# Ng-mock: $compileProvider doesn't have method 'preAssignBindingsEnabled`

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, components, angularjs-1.5, angularjs-ngmock

I've been rewriting directives in Angular 1.5.8 to components. I want to write unit tests with '$componentController` just like described here: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component.

The problem is that I'm getting error at this line:

`var ctrl = $componentController('componentName', null, bindings);`

saying: 
`undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'compileProvider.preAssignBindingsEnabled()')
    app/lib/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2235:80`

So it looks like $compileProvider doesn't have `preAssignBindingsEnabled` method at all. If anyone has an idea of what possibly I'm doing wrong I'd appreciate a little help.

Thanks!

**UPDATE:** jsFiddle of unit test: https://jsfiddle.net/kveb1ovo/2/

Comment: This Fiddle does not work...

Comment: It should be working now

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md why u think this option should exist in 1.5.8 ?

Comment: Turns out I had wrong version og ng-mocks installed (1.5.11 instead of 1.5.8). Thanks for pointing that out!